# Slow web requests on Android 4.3

Tags: android, http, url, webview, android-4.3-jelly-bean

I'm experiencing an issue on a Nexus 10 running Android 4.3 where network requests occasionally seem to be very slow. A request to a particular web service used in my project is known to be variable, but it seems that the upper limit of these variations is much larger on the Nexus 10 than on other devices (I've tested against the Nexus 5 running Android 4.4 and HTC Incredible on 2.3.5)

While I test more thoroughly and get some meaningful comparisons, I wanted to put this out there to see if anyone else had seen a similar difference between these OSs?

This seems to be happening for normal web pages loaded in Chrome, too. The Nexus 5 (4.4) loads a bbc.co.uk test page in 5-6s, whereas the Nexus 10 (4.3) manages 12-17s

Comment: In general, even 5-6s is very slow. I'd go mad after 1s

Comment: Yeah you should be loading information (depending on how big) in under 2 seconds. And thats still slow. Talk to your IT Department or whoever is in charge of maintaining the servers and see if they can help speed things up or what you guys can do to minimize that load time.

Comment: FYI the test page was a bbc.co.uk page loaded via Chrome. That was my control; I don't think that my IT department can help with that :P

Comment: @sleeke: I too have the same issues on Nexus 10 running Android 4.4. My WebView pages loads very very slow and most of the time they don't load at all. These pages works like a charm on other devices such as Nexus 4, Nexus 7 etc. Have you found any explanation/fix for this ?

Comment: I'm afraid I haven't. The issue was intermittent so I've had trouble tracing the bug. One thing I did notice is that javascript seems to have an impact on the load times. Without the javascript, the page loads much faster. I thought it had something to do with the javascript being executed on page load, but I seem to recall that load times were impacted even if the javascript wasn't set to run immediately.